# How to manage custom response code in web appliication

Tags: python, django, api, http, httpresponse

This question is more into the architectural one rather than code itself. I was curious how response codes are managed in enterprise and other big projects.

**Techstack**:

- Python 3
- Django

In any REST based web application we need to have some sort of custom response codes. These codes are different from our HTTP response codes.

**USE-CASE**:
Suppose we have an API for creating a Product record in the database. Now depending on some sort of business logic i want to return a custom response code like 2001, 2002 (or something else). HTTP response code will always be 200 but my custom response code could be different. These custom codes might be required for the client application to identify as to what to do next.

Generally i have seen people creating a List of dictionaries something else this:

```
codes = {"PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS": 2002, "PRODUCT_CREATE_FAIL": 2005, ......}
```

and same goes with response messages

```
messages = {"PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS": "Product created successfully", "PRODUCT_CREATE_FAIL": "Product already exist"}
```

So whenever they want to return these codes and messages they just do

```
{"code": codes['PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS'], "message": messages['PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS']}
```

I know the above approach suffice with smaller applications but it might be problematic for big ones. The answer can be a subjective one. Though i don't want to go into the coding part but we can if required.